# Rounding numbers to a specific value in Python

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I would like to do in python rounding to the specified value. Rounded to a tip or .99, 9.99 or other value. The value can by dynamic. 
Example:

Rounded to .99

```
20.11 => 20.99
11.33 = 11.99
1.00 = 1.99
```

Rounded to 9.99

```
100 => 109.99
293.33 => 299.99
```

Rounded to 0.33

```
1 => 1.33
34.44 => 35.33
```

How do that?

Comment: this is not rounding by any stretch of the imagination

Comment: "probably" his native language is not english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def roundAprox(a, b):
    c = 0
    while (pow(10, c) < b):
        c += 1

    result = int(a)
    return result - result % (pow(10, c)) + b
```

Let's test it:

```
print roundAprox(20.11, 0.99)
print roundAprox(11.33, 0.99)
print roundAprox(1.00, 0.99)
print roundAprox(100, 9.99)
print roundAprox(293.33, 9.99)
print roundAprox(1, 0.33)
print roundAprox(34.44, 0.33)
```

Result:

```
20.99
11.99
1.99
109.99
299.99
1.33
34.33
```

I assume that the last round to 0.33 is wrong, you wanted 34.44 to become 34.33

Comment: No the last one is correct. This is exactly what I want to achieve.